# Angular cdk - How to use horizontal button scroll along with drag and drop cdkScrollable

Tags: angular, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have used cdk drag and drop along with cdk-scrollable directive to achieve auto-scroll while the item is being dragged.

Drag and drop is working perfectly. But now the requirement is - we have to change the scrolling style from default to horizontal scrolling with left/right buttons.

[horizontal-scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onRCN.png)

For Horizontal scrolling, I have created a component with left right buttons and ng-content. And Encapsulated whole droplist container inside the horizontal-scrolling component.

Now the issue is, cdk drag drop with scrolling is not working fine with my custom scroll component.

container where drag and drop is implemented:

```html
<div cdkScrollable cdkDropList [cdkDropListAutoScrollStep]="2" class="example-list" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let chartItem of chartData; let i = index; let last = last;">
        <div class="example-box" [ngSwitch]="chartItem.type" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".example-list">
</div>
```

horizontal-scrolling component:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="widgetElement && leftButtonEnabled">
        <button (click)="scrollLeft()">left</button>
      </div>
    <div #widgetsContent class="custom-slider-main">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="widgetElement && rightButtonEnabled">
        <button (click)="scrollRight()">right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have encapsulated my main container like this:

```html
<mc-gallery-scroll>
  <div cdkScrollable cdkDropList [cdkDropListAutoScrollStep]="2" class="example-list" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let chartItem of chartData; let i = index; let last = last;">
              <div class="example-box" [ngSwitch]="chartItem.type" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".example-list">
      </div>
</mc-gallery-scroll>
```